# Problem in connecting Mosquitto broker with paho-mqtt native in RIOT OS

Tags: networking, mqtt, mosquitto, matter-iot-standard, riot-os

I am running the example project paho-mqtt natively on a Linux machine and have no problem following the instruction up until trying to connect to my local mosquitto broker.

The broker is running on the same host and is configered to listen to all IPv6 and IPv4 at port 1883. I connected my real with the virtual with `uplink eth0` so that my tapbr0 connects 2 interfaces tap0 and eth0. I can ping the bridge tapbr0 ip address, but when I run
`con [tapbr0 ip address]` it fails to connect.

The mosquitto broker is running fine but then I don’t understand why it didn’t work not sure with the example. Does anyone have any idea ?

my mosquitto.config

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
```

I use mosquitto version 2.0.11

listening sockets

```
tate         Recv-Q        Send-Q               Local Address:Port                 Peer Address:Port        Process        
LISTEN        0             4096                       0.0.0.0:111                       0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             4096                       0.0.0.0:8080                      0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             4096                 127.0.0.53%lo:53                        0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             100                        0.0.0.0:1883                      0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             4096                     127.0.0.1:45091                     0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN        0             4096                          [::]:111                          [::]:*
LISTEN        0             4096                          [::]:8080                         [::]:*
LISTEN        0             100                           [::]:1883                         [::]:*
```

bridge

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
docker0         8000.0242acb93c18       no              veth7071db4
tapbr0          8000.ce2cdb2ecb24       no              eth0
                                                        tap0
```

Comment: Show the code you are running

Comment: https://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/blob/master/examples/paho-mqtt/main.c It would be this one for the MQTT Client